# PostgreSQL: Drop Database but DB is still there

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am new to PostgreSQL and I try to get my head around it. I am familiar to db's and MySQL.

I am trying to delete database, which I created since psql seems to ignore the changes I try to push through Django.

When I execute `\l` I get the following response:

```
                                  List of databases
       Name       | Owner  | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    | Access privileges 
------------------+--------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------
 postgres         | neurix | UTF8     | en_AU.UTF-8 | en_AU.UTF-8 | 
 test_db          | neurix | UTF8     | en_AU.UTF-8 | en_AU.UTF-8 | 
 template0        | neurix | UTF8     | en_AU.UTF-8 | en_AU.UTF-8 | =c/neurix        +
                  |        |          |             |             | neurix=CTc/neurix
 template1        | neurix | UTF8     | en_AU.UTF-8 | en_AU.UTF-8 | =c/neurix        +
                  |        |          |             |             | neurix=CTc/neurix
 template_postgis | neurix | UTF8     | en_AU.UTF-8 | en_AU.UTF-8 | 
(5 rows)
```

Now I wan to drop the database "test_db" with

```
DROP DATABASE test_db
```

but when I execute `\l` afterwards, the table is still there and the overview looks like about.

Comment: You might also want to try with double quotes: `DROP DATABASE "mydb";`

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Did you type a `;` after the `DROP DATABASE test_db`? Did PostgreSQL print a response to your command?

Comment: Thank you - the ; was missing.

Comment: And that's why they pay me the big bucks. Semicolons on time, every time.

Comment: Semicolon -  the cornerstone of every notorious language

Comment: Also on my current version (11.2), capitalization is required: `drop database <name>;` fails, but `DROP DATABASE <name>;` succeeds.

Comment: @MattSanders Really? Works for me: `psql (11.2 (Debian 11.2-1.pgdg90+1))`
`Type "help" for help.` `postgres=# create database orly;` `CREATE DATABASE` `postgres=# drop database orly;` `DROP DATABASE`

Comment: Haha, it seems it was a single semi-colon making me struggle for several minutes. Thank u

Comment: Yeah, I did not spend minutes but - wait for it - hours trying to solve this "bug"

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue when working on a **Rails 6** application in **Ubuntu 20.04** with **PostgreSQL** as my database.

When I run the command:

```
DROP DATABASE my-db;
```

The database is dropped successfully, however, the schema for the database is still left.

So when I run the command:

```
CREATE DATABASE my-db;
```

And I check the tables in the newly created database, I realized they still contained the same tables as the previously deleted database, even though I have not run any migration.

**Here's how I fixed it**:

Instead of running the command:

```
DROP DATABASE my-db;
```

run the command:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS my-db;
```

This deletes the database and it's corresponding schema.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**