# postgres DROP command not working

Tags: python, django

I am unable to drop database/table.
Here are the sequence of commands I am running.

> psql
>
> \l

after seeing my database name(XXX),

> DROP DATABASE XXXX
>
> \l

XXX is still present.

I tried to restart the psql and also rebooted my laptop.I must be doing something wrong but it has consumed more than 2 hours. Any help?

Comment: Why would 'django.core.paginator' be in installed apps? It's not an app.

Comment: I don't have the link but I followed the steps to add pagination.And pagination started to work too.If you say so, I will remove that from installed apps and see if it is still working.

Comment: @Puneet what Django version are you using?

Comment: 1.8.4 . I tried migration command too. I am trying the suggestion provided by Bogdan but I cannot verify it since syncdb is not adding the new field in database and when i open the app in admin it crashes saying that particular field is not found

Comment: Here is the pagination documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/pagination/ But I don't see anything about adding the pagination module to INSTALLED_APPS, doesn;t make sense. I suggest you tell us what you trying to achieve. The whole picture, and maybe we can advice in the right direction.

Comment: @Bogdan I am adding a new field.Syncdb is not working. And I removed the pagination module from installed_app. If you can add your solution , I can mark that as the answer. For syncdb not adding the new field , I will add seperate question,if required.

Comment: It would be great if you print the traceback of your syncdb command (with pagination deleted from apps) here.

Comment: Migration is really a mess. I guess Django developers will change this part soon. I solve my problems with python manage.py sql [app_name] and add field manually to database. When you first create a model, syncdb works but not updates old ones. Migrate is also very confusing for me.

Answer (score 0):

So I have edited my question but now I feel i did for worse.Anyways, the solution to my problem was already present in stackoverflow. Sorry for duplication

[PostgreSQL: Drop Database but DB is still there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044379/postgresql-drop-database-but-db-is-still-there)